# Records linked to each other but prevent leveling and loops

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have a table of tags that user can freely create. Due to this *freedom* I have several tags that are aliases/synonyms of other tags. I would therefore like to create a table of tag aliases/synonyms.

```
create table dbo.TagAlias (
    TagId int not null
        references dbo.Tag(Id)
        primary key, -- prevent a tag being an alias of several tags
    RootTagId int not null
        references dbo.Tag(Id)
)
```

Suppose I have tags (let's say their IDs are 1, 2 and 3):

```
C#, CSharp, C# (c-sharp)
```

All of these are basically the same tag. So my table would have these records

```
TagId  RootTagId
----------------
2      1
3      1
----------------
```

I would of course like to prevent this from happening

- multi-level aliases/synonyms

  ```
  TagId  RootTagId
  ----------------
  2      1
  3      2
  ----------------
  ```
- alias/synonym loops

  ```
  TagId  RootTagId
  ----------------
  2      3
  3      2
  ----------------
  ```

Both would be solved with a simple check that if an ID is in the first column (`TagId`) then it can't be in the second column (`RootTagId`). This would prevent leveling as well as loops.

### Question

Is there a way for me to put this restriction/check directly on my database table using some sort of an index?

I know an *insert trigger* would be able to prevent this from happening albeit it would do a clustered index seek on each insert/update to check whether ID being inserted is already present as primary key.

Comment: Allow in `roottagid` only tags from the original `tags` table. Add a foreign key to it.

Comment: @juergend: I've updated my `create table` statement. I do have foreign key constraints set, but that doesn't prevent looping nor leveling.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by referencing back to the *root* tags table.  Have a table of root tags and just have a direct reference to that:

```
alter table tagalias add constraint foreign key (RootTagId) references RootTags(TagId);
```

If you don't have a root tags table, I believe you can do the same thing with a filtered index and a reference.

```
create unique index idx_tagalias_tagid on tagalis(tagid, roottagid)
    where roottagid is null;

alter table tagalias add constraint foreign key (RootTagId) references RootTags(tagId, roottagid);
```

EDIT:

Your data structure does *exactly* what you want.  But, you are confused because `RootTagId` and `TagId` have the same values, but don't refer to the same object.  For example:

```
TagId  RootTagId
----------------
2      1
3      2
```

Say `RootTagId` 1 is "C#" and 2 is `SQL`.  Then *tagid* = 2 might be "c-sharp" and *tagid* = 3 might be "sequel".  That's fine.  The two entities are actually different:  one is the alias and one is the tag.

You can store all the root tags in the `TagAlias` table.  Then, you can just use the `TagAlias` for referring to any "alias" tag (including the root one).  And, you can extract the root tags when you need to.

Comment: I didn't add the foreign key constraint to both columns. They both reference dbo.Tag(Id) column. But this alone still doesn't prevent loops out leveling...

Comment: Updated my question to include foreign key constraints to my `TagAlias` table.